# How to deactivate or override the Android "BACK" button, in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to deactivate the Android back button when on a specific page?

```
class WakeUpApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Time To Wake Up ?",
      home: new WakeUpHome(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/pageOne': (BuildContext context) => new pageOne(),
        '/pageTwo': (BuildContext context) => new pageTwo(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

On pageOne I have a button to go to pageTwo:

```
new FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {    
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/pageTwo');
  },
)
```

My problem is that if I press the Back arrow at the bottom of the android screen, I go back to pageOne. I would like this button to not show up at all. 
Ideally, I would like to have no possible way out of this screen unless the user for example keeps his finger pressed on the screen for 5 seconds. (I am trying to write an App for toddlers, and would like only the parents to be able to navigate out of the particular screen).

Answer (score 446, accepted):

The answer is `WillPopScope`. It will prevent the page from being popped by the system. You'll still be able to use `Navigator.of(context).pop()`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("data"),
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: For those wanting to intercept the pop of a Form, it's more convenient to use the Form's `onWillPop` property. It has access to the form state and can first check to see if there is any state that the user might not want to lose.

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet , Can you please help me on the back stack manage like I have a stack of A, B , C, D screens and I want to navigate from the D->B OR D->A , then how will I manage it. Can you please guide me on it

Comment: I know this answer maybe old.  But is a GEM!  Think about expanding the explanation.  It work superb.  Thank you.

Comment: For someone want to do something before pop(), can use this `onWillPop: () async {
        onBack();  // "DO YOUR FUNCTION IS HERE WHEN POP" 

        return false;
      }`

Comment: As of version 3.16 `WillPopScope` has been deprecated. the replacement is `PopScope`. Simply providing with `canPop: false` will disable the popping of current route. If you need to execute some code on back press, use `onPopInvoked` parameter.

Answer (score 57):

As Rémi Rousselet pointed out, `WillPopScope` is usually the way to go. However, if you are developing a stateful widget that should react to the back button directly, you may use this:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/back_button_interceptor

*Note: I am the author of this package.*

Comment: @CopsOnRoad No, since it's not a comment to another answer, but rather a totally different way to solve the same problem.

Comment: It's a good alternative and it could have been ignored if it was part of a comment.

Comment: It's a great alternative, works like a charm and thanks for highlighting it in a separate answer

Answer (score 49):

While Remi's answer is right, usually you don't want to simply block the back button but want a user to confirm the exit.

You can do it similar way by getting an answer from the confirmation dialog, because `onWillPop` is a future.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    child: Scaffold(...),
    onWillPop: () => showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (c) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Warning'),
        content: Text('Do you really want to exit'),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Yes'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(c, true),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('No'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(c, false),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I want to go to the previous screen rather going to the first screen after pressing back button from device. I dont need a dialog box like this. What should I do

Answer (score 19):

You can use `Future.value(bool)` to handle the back button.

```
bool _allow = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    child: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Back"))),
    onWillPop: () {
      return Future.value(_allow); // if true allow back else block it
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: FYI, this is equivalent to `onWillPop: () async => _allow`.

Comment: @Lynn yes I know that. I just wanted to share `Future.value()` call.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad return SafeArea() already defined then how to handle back pressed in a flutter

Comment: @CopsOnRoad hi, in my class code                                                                 

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[ ..... so here return WillPopScope( ); cannot define two return statement then how to initialize backpressed in flutter

Comment: @s.j Wrap your `SafeArea` widget in `WillPopScope`.

Answer (score 10):

The answer maybe you knew that's use **WillPopScope**,but unfortunately on **IOS** you can't ***swipe to back*** the previous page, so let's custom your MaterialPageRoute:

```
class CustomMaterialPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  @protected
  bool get hasScopedWillPopCallback {
    return false;
  }
  CustomMaterialPageRoute({
    @required WidgetBuilder builder,
    RouteSettings settings,
    bool maintainState = true,
    bool fullscreenDialog = false,
  }) : super( 
          builder: builder,
          settings: settings,
          maintainState: maintainState,
          fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog,
        );
}
```

Now you can use WillPopScope and **swipe to back** will work on IOS. The details answer is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203#issuecomment-540663717

Answer (score 9):

Just a simple method. Wrap Scaffold with WillPopScope widget.

```
  WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: Scaffold();
```

Answer (score 8):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918186/19544859) is outdated

[`WillPopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) is now [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation), and shouldn't be used anymore. Reference: [Android Predictive Back](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back)

> To support Android 14’s Predictive Back feature, a set of ahead-of-time APIs have replaced just-in-time navigation APIs, like WillPopScope and Navigator.willPop.

---

### Replacement

If you're using version **3.14.0-7.0.pre** of Flutter or greater, you should replace `WillPopScope` widgets with [`PopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html). It has 2 fields:

- `bool canPop`, enables/disables system back gestures (pop);
- `void Function(bool didPop)? onPopInvoked`, is a callback that's *always* invoked on system back gestures, even if `canPop` is set to false, but in this case the route will not be popped off, and [`didPop`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/didPop.html) will be set to false (so you can check its value to discriminate the logic).

### Answer

To answer your question:

- if you want to **deactivate** the "back" button (i.e. disable system back gesture) you can set `canPop: false`;
- if you want to **override** its behaviour, you can set `canPop: true` (or calculate its value with some logic condition or a sync function) and set a callback with `onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {}`.

### Example

```dart
PopScope(
  canPop: _isSettingsChanged(),
  onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
    if (didPop) {
      return;
    }
    final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    final bool? shouldPop = await _showConfirmDialog("Unsaved settings. Discard?");
    if (shouldPop ?? false) {
      navigator.pop();
    }
  },
  child: child,
)
```

Comment: This is the right answer for the time being. I didn't do anything more than just upgrade the Flutter 3.16.1.

Answer (score 7):

I'm posting this here in case anyone out there finds this and wishes they would find a simple example
https://gist.github.com/b-cancel/0ca372017a25f0c120b14dfca3591aa5

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(new BackButtonOverrideDemoWidget());

class BackButtonOverrideDemoWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _BackButtonOverrideDemoWidgetState createState() => new _BackButtonOverrideDemoWidgetState();
}

class _BackButtonOverrideDemoWidgetState extends State<BackButtonOverrideDemoWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver{

  //-------------------------Test Variable

  bool isBackButtonActivated = false;

  //-------------------------Required For WidgetsBindingObserver

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  //-------------------------Function That Triggers when you hit the back key

  @override
  didPopRoute(){
    bool override;
    if(isBackButtonActivated)
      override = false;
    else
      override = true;
    return new Future<bool>.value(override);
  }

  //-------------------------Build Method

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: new Container(
          color: (isBackButtonActivated) ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          child: new Center(
              child: new FlatButton(
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  isBackButtonActivated = !isBackButtonActivated;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: (isBackButtonActivated) ?
                new Text("DeActive the Back Button") : new Text("Activate the Back Button"),
              )
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I literally used it myself yesterday. Keep in mind that it is only for Android, Apple has no back button. Although could you perhaps tell me what goes wrong so I can repair it, or perhaps it only works on my particular emulator. I haven't updated my flutter in a couple weeks so perhaps that's the problem. Let me know

Comment: @BryanCancel Your answer works only if you don't yet have any pushed routes. See method WidgetsBinding.handlePopRoute(). It notifies the observers in registration order, and stops as soon as it receives true. When there are pushed routes, the navigator returns true first, and then your observer never actually gets called. In other words, your code only works to prevent the application from shutting down when the user clicks the back button, when there are no more routes left.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative solution that works if you're coding with null safety. You need to disable the the default back button, and replace it with an IconButton. In this example, I'm pushing an AlertDialog when the user clicks the back button to confirm before exiting. You can replace this function and send the user to any other page

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => false,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
      title: Text(),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () => showDialog<bool>(
          context: context,
          builder: (c) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Warning'),
            content: Text('Are you sure you want to exit?'),
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  child: Text('Yes'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(c, true);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }),
              TextButton(
                child: Text('No'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(c, false),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Use a `BackButtonIcon()` to get the appropriate icon for the platform.

Answer (score 4):

Trying this will kill your app state

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      ////////////////
      onWillPop: () => showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (c) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'Warning',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          content: Text('Are you sure to exit?'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.green,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                exit(0);// kill app
              },
              child: Text('Yes'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.red,
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(c, false),
              child: Text('No'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      /////////////////////
      child: Scaffold(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I used mixin and WillPopScope widget just couldn't get the job done for me.
This is best approach I found, much better than WillPopScope in my opinion.
`final bool canPop = ModalRoute.of(context)?.canPop ?? false;`
Used it like this inside appbar:

```
leading: ModalRoute.of(context)?.canPop ?? false
    ? IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        icon: (Platform.isAndroid)
            ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
            : const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
      )
    : Container(),
```

Answer (score 2):

`WillPopScope` is a good solution, and with `onWillPop: () async => false` the back button is disabled, but the icon is still there.

**To remove and disable the back button just use `leading: Container()` in `AppBar`.**

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to have different behavior for system back button tap, and app bar back button tap: you can remove the `onWillPop` callback before calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()`:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ModalRoute.of(context)?.removeScopedWillPopCallback(onWillPop);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          ),
          title: Text(context.l10n.searchResults),
        ),
        body: MyBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In this case when user will tap system back button, `onWillPop` callback will decide should the screen be popped or not. But when user will tap app bar back button, screen will be popped immediatly.

Answer (score 1):

Since Flutter Version 3.16.2 the `WillPopScope` Widget is **deprecated**.

Here is the new way to to this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Push to Page but disable possibility to pop page
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const PopScope(
            canPop: false,
            child: NextPage(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: const Text("Naviagte to Page"),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using generated route you can return to destination page by doing this-

```
AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
         onPressed: () {
         Navigator.of(context) .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(AppRouter.dashboard, (route) => false);
         }),
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a quick exit:

```dart
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/your_page_route');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Flutter version 3.12.0 WillPopScope is deprecated.

You can use `PopScope`
ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
AppBar(
          leadingWidth: 0,
          leading: Container(),
          ...)
```

Just like that!

Comment: This just removes the *AppBar widget back button* and has nothing to do with the ***Android back button***, which was the subject of OP question. Also it wasn't specified anywhere in the question that he's using an AppBar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution from mikyll98 did not close my app but showed a black screen. The following solution worked for me:

```
return PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
          if (didPop) {
            return;
          }

          final bool? shouldPop = await _closeAppDialog(context);
          if (shouldPop ?? false) {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

**WillPopScope** is deprecated after `v3.12.0` onwards use Use `PopScope` instead

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("data"),
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new PopScope class (Flutter SDK 3.16.x or greater)

```
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageOne({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      onPopInvoked: (_) async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/pageTwo');
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PopScope` instead of the depreciated Widget `WillPopScope`

```
PopScope(
    ///[true] if the page should pop, else false
    canPop: true/false,
    onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
      ///didPop boolean indicates whether or not back navigation
      /// succeeded.
      if (didPop) {
        return;
      }
      ///Your logic saying what should happen
      ///if the screen is not popped

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: 0,
        foregroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?