# catch Android back button event on Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Is there any way I can catch the `onBackPressed` event from Android back button?

I've tried the `WillPopScope` but my `onWillPop` function only triggered when I tap on the Material back arrow button

I put it like this:

```
class MyView extends StatelessWidget{

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        debugPrint("Will pop");
        return true;
      },
      child: ScopedModel<AppModel>(
      model: new AppModel(),
      child: new Scaffold(......
```

I need to catch it because somehow my screen behaved incorrectly when it came to back button  pressed, it pops the screen and the screen below it, but somehow, using material back arrow button works normal.

Update:

The code works, my problem was not in the pop of this screen, but on the previous screen, I use 2 MaterialApp widgets, and somehow it gave a weird behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [De-activate system back button in Flutter App (toddler navigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/de-activate-system-back-button-in-flutter-app-toddler-navigation)

Comment: make sure you have a single `MaterialApp` widget for you entire app.

Answer (score 105):

In order to prevent navigating back [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) is the correct way and should be used as follow:

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Page 2'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text('PAGE 2'),
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
    );
  }
}

Future<T> pushPage<T>(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
  return Navigator.of(context)
      .push<T>(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
}
```

Can call the page like:

```
pushPage(context, Page2());
```

Comment: I tried this and get the same result, it prevents the navigation from the back arrow but cannot prevent it when I push the Android back button

Comment: @RizkyAndriawan this code works even with hard back button. Please try this code first.

Comment: what if you just want to stop a process before returning back to the previous screen? I followed this example and i could stop the process but can't return back

Comment: Found it. According to docs(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html), to return to the previous screen, onWillPop should return Future(() => true);  thanks

Answer (score 27):

This is should be helpful.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () {
      _moveToScreen2(context, );
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              _moveToScreen2(context);
            }),
        title: Text("Screen 1"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
* This is probably too thin to be in its own method - consider using
* `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "screen2")` directly
*/
void _moveToScreen2(BuildContext context) =>
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "screen2");
```

Comment: Is it possible to navigate different page when clixk device back button using this way?

Comment: @BloodLoss Yeah, I all you'll probably have to do is change `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.keySignIn);` to `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "{your-destination-route-key}");`

Comment: It's working using ```Navigator.pushReplacement()```

Comment: `WillPopScope` is deprecated , Use `PopScope`, and use Navigator `.canPop()` instead of `.pop()`

Answer (score 19):

Use **WillPopScope** method and return **false**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
     onWillPop: () async {
        // Do something here
        print("After clicking the Android Back Button");
        return false;
     },
     child: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Handling the back button"),
       ),
       body: Center(
          child: Text("Body"),
       ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future<bool>', as required by the closure's

Comment: This is worked as expected

Answer (score 6):

You can use [back_button_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor)

it detects hardware back button & will be so useful specially in case of using persistent_bottom_nav_bar

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BackButtonInterceptor.remove(myInterceptor);
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent, RouteInfo info) {
    print("BACK BUTTON!"); // Do some stuff.
    return false;// return true if u want to stop back
  }
```

Comment: This is the working one. The `WillPopScope` just catch route level dismiss

Answer (score 5):

Just adding an important point here.
Please note that by using `WillPopScope`, we will lose the back swipe gesture on iOS.

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203

Answer (score 4):

This code work for me.

I think there may be two reasons.

1. Child of WillPopScope is Scaffold
2. No return in onWillPop

   ```
   return new WillPopScope(
     onWillPop: () {
       if (!_isOpened) Navigator.pop(context);
     },
     child: new Scaffold(
       key: SharedService.orderScaffoldKey,
       appBar: appBar,
       body: new Builder(
         builder: (BuildContext context) {
           return page;
         },
       ),
     ),
   );
   ```

Answer (score 3):

[`WillPopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) is now [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation), and shouldn't be used anymore. Reference: [Android Predictive Back](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back)

> To support Android 14’s Predictive Back feature, a set of ahead-of-time APIs have replaced just-in-time navigation APIs, like WillPopScope and Navigator.willPop.

If you try using it, you'll get the following warning:

```
'WillPopScope.new' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.
Use PopScope instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.12.0-1.0.pre.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
```

### Replacement

If you're using version **3.14.0-7.0.pre** of Flutter or greater, you should replace `WillPopScope` widgets with [`PopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html). It has 2 fields:

- `bool canPop`, enables/disables system back gestures (pop);
- `void Function(bool didPop)? onPopInvoked`, is a callback that's *always* invoked on system back gestures, even if `canPop` is set to false, but in this case the route will not be popped off, and [`didPop`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/didPop.html) will be set to false (so you can check its value to discriminate the logic).

### Migration Example

With `WillPopScope`:

```dart
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    final bool? shouldPop = await _showBackDialog();
    return shouldPop ?? false;
  },
  child: child,
)
```

With `PopScope`:

```dart
PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
    if (didPop) {
      return;
    }
    final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    final bool? shouldPop = await _showBackDialog();
    if (shouldPop ?? false) {
      navigator.pop();
    }
  },
  child: child,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the documentation of BackButtonListener:

```
/// It can be useful for scenarios, in which you create a different state in your
/// screen but don't want to use a new page for that.
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/79642

e.g.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackButtonListener(
      onBackButtonPressed: () {
        /// todo: close search widget
        if(searchBarController.isClose()){
            return false;
        }else{
            searchBarController.close();
            return Future.value(true);
        }
      },
      child: SearchBar(controller: searchBarController),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the updated code

basically, *WillPopScope -> onWillPop* works on the future argument
we can say as *when it happens then* ????
so as soon the back button is pressed WillPopScope -> onWillPop gets activated and listens to the argument more specific the back button event to pop it (replace it)
Most of the time I use it to show a DialogBox of Future type because it will only appear when it is needed same can be used to navigate to a new screen as well (hope so) preferred to do MaterialPage routing or named routing techniques for navigation,
use WillPopScope for the hardware back button event listening *(hardware = Android/IOs)* to show the exit popup

> code is already been given above but does not work for me so I change a little bit

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async{
      return _moveToScreen2(context);
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              _moveToScreen2(context);
            }),
        title: Text("Screen 1"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Future<bool>_moveToScreen2(BuildContext context) =>
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "screen2");
```

===============================================

> What I do on Exit

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: ()=> showExitPopup(context)
    child: Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Screen 1"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

=========================================

**On Back button Press**
created a dart file with the name **showExitPopup**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vexpositions/Servises/ConstantManager.dart';

Future<bool> showExitPopup(context) async{
  return await showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: SizedBox(
            height: 90,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
               const Text("Want to Exit the app!"),
               const SizedBox(height:20),
               Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('yes selected');
                          exit(0);
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.white),
                        child: const Text("Yes", style: TextStyle(color: 
                       Colors.black)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 15),
                    Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('no selected');
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.red.shade800,
                          ),
                          child: const Text("No", style: TextStyle(color: 
                          Colors.white)),
                        ))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way todo this is to implement a `NavigatorObserver` and link it to the `MaterialApp`:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

You don't have to use `RouteAware`, you can also implement your own `NavigatorObserver`.

This is for example how Flutter analytics works to automatically track screen opens/closes:

```
        MaterialApp(
          ...
          navigatorObservers: [
           FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
          ],
        )
```

`FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` extends the `RouteObserver` which itself implements `NavigatorObserver`.

However `WillPopScope` is often the easier solution

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  DateTime? _lastPressedAt;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async{

        bool shouldCloseApp = false;
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        if (_lastPressedAt == null || now.difference(_lastPressedAt!) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
          // If this is the first time the user presses back or more than 2 seconds
          // have passed since the last press, show a message
          _lastPressedAt = now;
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('Press back again to close the app.'),
          ));
        } else {
          // If this is the second time the user presses back within 2 seconds,
          // set shouldCloseApp to true to exit the app
          shouldCloseApp = true;
        }

        return shouldCloseApp;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```