# Flutter app back button event not redirecting to back page

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter android app. It have three screens. Page 1, Page 2, Page 3. When i entering Page 3 from Page 2. if i click phone back button it want to got to page 2.
But it is redirecting to page 1. I tried after got the reference from
[catch Android back button event on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452710/catch-android-back-button-event-on-flutter)

I tried `WillPopScope` . It is not entering in `onWillPop` .

How to solve the problem. My code is shown below.

**page 1**

```
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(),
            body: MyAppPage()
        ),
        );
    }
    }

    class MyAppPage extends StatefulWidget{
    MyAppPage({Key key,}):super(key:key);

    @override
    _MyAppPageState createState()=> new _MyAppPageState();
    }

    class _MyAppPageState extends State<MyAppPage>{

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return new Scaffold(
        body:RaisedButton(onPressed:(){ Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));},
        child: new Text("got to page 1"),)
        );
    }
    }
```

**page 2**

```
    class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(),
            body: SecondPage()
        ),
        );
    }
    }

    class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget{
    SecondPage({Key key,}):super(key:key);
    @override
    SecondPageState createState()=> new SecondPageState();
    }

    class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage>{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return new Scaffold(
            body:Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                new Center(
                child: new Text("Page 2"),
                ),
                RaisedButton(onPressed:(){ Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdScreen()));},
                child: new Text("go to third Page 3"),)
            ],
            )
        );
    }
    }
```

**page 3**

```
    class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(),
            body: ThirdPage()
        ),
        );
    }
    }

    class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget{
    ThirdPage({Key key,}):super(key:key);
    @override
    ThirdPageState createState()=> new ThirdPageState();
    }

    class ThirdPageState extends State<ThirdPage>{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return new WillPopScope(
        child: new Scaffold(
            body:  new Center(
            child: new Text('PAGE 3'),
            ),
        ),
        onWillPop: (){
            debugPrint("onWillPop");
            return new Future(() => false);
        },
        );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kinda got confused with the `Screen` and `Pages` you created. You actually have more Widgets than you need.

This is what you probably want to do.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyAppPage());
  }
}

class MyAppPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppPageState createState() => _MyAppPageState();
}

class _MyAppPageState extends State<MyAppPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 1")),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Text("got to page 1")),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Go to Page 2"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 2")),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text("I'm in Page 2"),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdPage()));
            },
            child: Text("go to third Page 3"),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}

class ThirdPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThirdPageState createState() => _ThirdPageState();
}

class _ThirdPageState extends State<ThirdPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 3")),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Text('PAGE 3')),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("aditional back button"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya I got the answer. I avoid stateless and use stateful. Thanks

Comment: Don't avoid Stateless, it's useful> :) However, if it's a page with a Scaffold, you need that state - and keep the ratio one page x one scaffold, you were nesting many in the same page.

Comment: But I want to write the code in different files. For example I write stateless in page1, Page 2 and page 3 I written in different dart file without stateless. Is it fine?

Comment: you can write all that in multiple files regardless of it being stateless ou stateful! 

Comment: Any suggestions if you already have such a simple setup and the back button is still not working? Even using the `WillPopScope` and just putting ` onWillPop:  () async => Navigator.of(context).pop()` in there doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

On your 3rd page, try to use

```
 onWillPop: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
```

Comment: I Tried this one but not working. It is not entering in onWillPop method.

Answer (score 0):

for my case, I should upgrade the flutter `master` branch to the latest code.

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade --force
flutter doctor -v
```