# Device back button not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Application when i click on back button of device it is closing app. I used Willpopscope but it is not working. But when i create a sample project it is working. Can Any one explain me why it is not working in existing application. I shared my code.  (In Appbar back arrow working fine but issue is with device back button)

```
    Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
                content: new Text('Unsaved data will be lost.'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                    child: new Text('No'),
                  ),
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                    child: new Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ) ??
        false;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(
            "On Back pressed", 
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you need to show your code please

Comment: @SamiKanafani I'm edited my code please check it

Comment: block to return back you have to modify your onWillPop property below 
()async{ return false; }

Comment: @MuratAslan I didn't understand, please explain once.

Comment: check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800603/flutter-app-back-button-event-not-redirecting-to-back-page/64071809#64071809

Answer (score 1):

replace your `_onWillPop` method with this `_onWillPop()async{ return false; }`

Comment: I'm trying this, it is not working when I click the back button app closed.

Comment: D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(11690): stop checker.
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(11690): Current Activity:false
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(11690): not watching, wait.
W/libEGL  (11690): EGLNativeWindowType 0x74e4b8b010 disconnect failed
I/SurfaceView(11690): delay destroy surface control
W/libEGL  (11690): EGLNativeWindowType 0x74e4b69010 disconnect failed
I/SurfaceView(11690): need destroy surface control
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](11690): surface should not be released

Answer (score 1):

[WillPopScope#onWillPop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope/onWillPop.html) doesn't allow the pop to occur if it returns a `false` value. You can try something like this if you don't want to show an `AlertDialog`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(
            "On Back pressed",
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text("Home Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: showing an error>> The return type 'bool' isn't a 'Future<bool>', as defined by anonymous closure