# Device back button does not go to the previous Screen in the memory stack and WillPopScope widget does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-widget

I have three screens in the example app - `HomeScreen`, `ScreenOne` and `ScreenTwo`. Navigation is implemented using a custom Drawer widget. Tapping on the phone's back button goes back to the home screen instead of the previous screen in the memory stack. I tried resolving the issue by using a `WillPopScope` widget in the home property of the `ScreenTwo` widget's `MaterialApp` Widget but `onWillPop` does not get called for the `ScreenTwo` widget.  Instead it gets called only when it is included in the `HomeScreen` widget. I have no idea why this is happening. I can also not understand why the using the phone's back button does not go back to the previous screen in the memory stack. How to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

`home_screen.dart` file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'drawer_widget.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            drawer: DrawerWidget(),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("WillPopScope Demo"),
              leading: Builder(
                builder: (context) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Home Screen"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

`screen_one.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'drawer_widget.dart';

class ScreenOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              drawer: DrawerWidget(),
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("WillPop Scope Demo"),
                leading: Builder(
                  builder: (context) => IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              body: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Screen One"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

`screen_two.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'drawer_widget.dart';

class ScreenTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              drawer: DrawerWidget(),
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("WillPop Scope Demo"),
                leading: Builder(
                  builder: (context) => IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              body: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Screen Two"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

`drawer_widget.dart` file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'screen_one.dart';
import 'screen_two.dart';

class DrawerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 275,
      color: Colors.grey[900],
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Home Screen", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Screen One", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenOne()));
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Screen Two", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenTwo()));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try again by changing this code:

```
onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenTwo()));
            },
```

to

```
onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenTwo()));
           },
```

Comment: I had added ```Navigator.pop(context)``` to pop the drawer when I navigate to the new screen. Even when I remove this line from the code, the problem does not go away. Instead, it now shows the drawer on the ```HomeScreen``` widget, no matter which screen I navigate from.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800603/flutter-app-back-button-event-not-redirecting-to-back-page) post. I created a `MyApp` Stateless Widget and passed the `HomeScreen` widget to this `MyApp` widget. I removed the extra MaterialApp widgets from the `ScreenOne` and `ScreenTwo` widgets. I kept everything else the same in the code. `WillPopScope` worked as did using the device's back button after implementing this change in the code. Strangely, this worked, considering it wasn't a problem with some of my other apps. Unrelated, but I had not upgraded the Flutter plugin in Android Studio after last upgrading the Flutter SDK. I upgraded the Flutter plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

From ...
WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
....
);

To.....
WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () async => false,
.....
);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).