# what is the equivalent method of onbackpressed in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want the same `onBackPressed` logic of Android in flutter application and I want to close the app when I click on phone back button.

Can any one tell me how to do this when we click on phone back not app back button.

android:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show dialog
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [catch Android back button event on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452710/catch-android-back-button-event-on-flutter)

Comment: Refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356664/how-to-override-the-back-button-in-flutter

Comment: @Ishant i think WillPopScope  is for app back button ,,,,not for phone back button right?

Comment: @kartheekij WillPopScope works for both

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) for that.
It's a class that notifies you when the enclosing `ModalRoute` (internally used with the `Navigator`) is *about to be popped*. It even leaves you a choice to whether or not you want the pop to happen.

Just wrap the second screen's `Scaffold` in a `WillPopScope`.

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    // You can do some work here.
    // Returning true allows the pop to happen, returning false prevents it.
    return true;
  },
  child: ... // Your Scaffold goes here.
);
```

Comment: Drawback of this solution is that back gesture on iOS then is no longer working.

Comment: in android device getting a black screen with WillPopScope tried all solutions with a navigator in flutter

Answer (score 5):

Hope this will help...

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
    // Your back press code here...
    CommonUtils.showToast(context, "Back presses");
}
```

WillPopScope creates a widget that registers a callback to veto attempts by the user to dismiss the enclosing ModalRoute.

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
        child: ...child
    );
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this solution works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Navigator.pop(context);` or `Navigator.maybePop(context);`;

And `maybePop` can be listened by `WillPopScope#onWillPop`；