# How to intercept back button in AppBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, back-button

I am using interceptor https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/back_button_interceptor to execute a method when the page 1 is back from page 2.

If I come back from page 2 to page 1 using device back button, the method is executed.

But if I come back from page 2 to page 1 using the arrow button at appBar I am not able to execute the method.

How can the back arrow button functionality default to the device back button?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deactivate or override the Android "BACK" button, in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can surround your scaffold on Page 2 with WillPopScope, set onWillPop to false to prevent the page from being popped by the system and then add your own back button into the app bar's leading widget and perform your pop in there.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("data"),
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

code for the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918186/1463174)

**Edit: Addition to Page 2 to control navigation**

In addition to the above code you'll add the below code to page 2. Change

```
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

to

```
Navigator.of(context).pop('upload_files')
```

Then in your page 1 where you navigate you'll await the navigation and use the result returned from the pop on page 2 and run your logic

```
var navigationResult = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Page2()));


 if(navigationResult == 'upload_files') {
    uploadFiles(); // Perform your custom functionality here.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your looking into it, This does not change anything, I want to mention again that I am using interceptor at page 1 to call a method when the page is back from page 2. That method call is working from the device back button. But when I come back from page 2 to page 1 using the back button at AppBar the method is not called.

Comment: @ningomba2.0 I don't know if you read the answer properly. You replace the back button in the appBar with your own button then you can call what you want in there? Is the onPressed callback firing in your leading widget?

Comment: That is right, I replace it  as like you mention above using the leading property. The callback is firing.

Comment: @ningomba2.0 so then the answer is correct? You can just call the same method you want to call from there and handle it as you mention in your first scenario

Comment: I will try to upload the files, I think I am not able to explain clearly. I am using interceptor at page 1 and not in page 2. I mentioned that I want to execute a function in page 1 when it is back from page 2.

Comment: @ningomba2.0 ooooooooooooh. Well that's very different answer. I'll update my answer now for your needs.

Comment: @ningomba2.0 I updated the answer for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Stacks that is doing the trick, that is exactly I am looking for. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: @ningomba2.0 you're very welcome. If you have other flutter questions that's not getting answered contact me in the direct messages and I'll see if I can assist you.

Comment: Under AppBar(...) you may need to add automaticallyImplyLeading: false,

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor

Answer (score 14):

The default back button in `AppBar` is `BackButton` widget from `material.dart`. You may create it manually and pass your own `onPressed` to do what you want:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: BackButton(onPressed: _onBackPressed),
    title: Text('Title'),
  ),
  body: Container(),
);
```

If you do not specify `leading` in `AppBar`, then it creates a `BackButton` with the handler that does `Navigator.maybePop(context)`.

Comment: Way easier than the accepted answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**WillPopScope** is deprecated after `v3.12.0` onwards use Use `PopScope` instead

```
  return new PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Some Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
```