# WillPopScope is deprecated in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform, deprecated

'WillPopScope' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use PopScope instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.12.0-1.0.pre

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    // your logic        
    return false;
  },
)
```

Comment: Please read at https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back

Comment: Use PopScope - https://www.aravi.me/blog/willpopscope-is-now-popscope-in-flutter/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Solved**

replace old widget from `WillPopScope` to `PopScope` new widget check below code

```
/// NEW CODE
PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked : (didPop){
   // logic
  },
)
```

Comment: that doesn't answer at all how the new class works. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html

Comment: And make canPop: false, as Apurv Thakkar answer.

Comment: to prevent the pop, you can set `canPop` to false and handle the pop manually by using `onPopInvoked` and use `Navigator.pop(context)`

Answer (score 24):

You can use it like this.

```
PopScope(
 canPop: false,
 onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
  if (didPop) {
    return;
  }
  final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
  bool value = await someFunction();
  if (value) {
    navigator.pop();
  }
},
```

Comment: ```  if (didPop) {
    return;
  }```
is a dead code, the `didPop` only return true when the route successfully popped. while we set `canPop` to false, there's no chance `didPop` will be true

if you want to prevent the pop, you can set `canPop` to false and handle the pop manually by using `onPopInvoked`

Comment: @AngDrew In the case of popUntil / pushAndRemoveUntil etc.. it will give you a true value, even if you have set canPop:false

Answer (score 7):

```
PopScope(
  canPop: false,  //It should be false to work
  onPopInvoked : (didPop) {
   if (didPop) {
      return;
    }
    Get.back(); //Here this temporary, you can change this line
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
PopScope(
      canPop: canPop,
      onPopInvoked: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          canPop= !value;
        });

        if (canPop) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text("Click once more to go back"),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      child:child)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const NavigatorPopHandlerApp());

class NavigatorPopHandlerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigatorPopHandlerApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => const _HomePage(),
        '/two': (BuildContext context) => const _PageTwo(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class _HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _HomePage();

  @override
  State<_HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<_HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Page One'),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/two');
              },
              child: const Text('Next page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  const _PageTwo();

  @override
  State<_PageTwo> createState() => _PageTwoState();
}

class _PageTwoState extends State<_PageTwo> {
  void _showBackDialog() {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text(
            'Are you sure you want to leave this page?',
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Nevermind'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Leave'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Page Two'),
            PopScope(
              canPop: false,
              onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
                if (didPop) {
                  return;
                }
                _showBackDialog();
              },
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _showBackDialog();
                },
                child: const Text('Go back'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a copy paste of https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html

Comment: I am just posting the credits for the real source, for whoever may need the complete context for further details.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current working solution:
You can wrap it around your screen in the router and it redirects to your home screen or it shows the snackbar with then closing the app after another press on the go back button.

```
class GoBackOrCloseOnConfirmationState
    extends State<GoBackOrCloseOnConfirmation> {
  DateTime? currentBackPressTime;
  bool allowPop = false;

  bool closeOnConfirm() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime!) > const Duration(seconds: 4)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          content: Center(child: Text('Drücke erneut um die App zu schließen')),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
        ),
      );
      return false;
    }
    currentBackPressTime = null;
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) => {
        widget.closeAppOnConfirmation
            ? closeOnConfirm()
                ? SystemNavigator.pop()
                : null
            : context.go('/')
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<bool> _onback(BuildContext context) async {
bool? exitApp = await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: ((context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('¿Quieres salir?',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
          )),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
            child: const Text('No')),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _flutterRadioPlayer.pause();
              _flutterRadioPlayer.stop();
              //exit(0);
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: const Text('Si'))
      ],
    );
  }),
);

return exitApp ?? false;
```

}

```
PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
    debugPrint("didPop1: $didPop");
    if (didPop) {
      return;
    }
    final bool shouldPop = await _onback(context);
    if (shouldPop) {
      SystemNavigator.pop();
    }
  },
  child:
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).