# How to imitate onWillPop in PopScope widget?

Tags: flutter

current code:

```dart
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page ({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => showConfirmExitDialog(context),
      child: Scaffold(...),
    );
  }
}
```

How to migrate this logic to `PopScope` widget?

Solution like bellow can't be used because it does pop twice (first was called by flutter before `onPopInvoked` and not yet completed)

```dart
PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (value) async {
    final result = await showConfirmExitDialog(context);
    if (!context.mounted) return;
    if (result) Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
```

Comment: Hey, Have you tried using PopScope, instead of `onWillPop: ()` you need to use `onPopInvoked: (value)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WillPopScope is deprecated in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77529904/willpopscope-is-deprecated-in-flutter)

Comment: @ ibhavikmakwana
no, because solution in provided question emits error `'!_debugLocked': is not true`.
In short, we can't use `pop` inside `onPopInvolved`. I have updated description

Comment: Check this out, if this helps

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77624361/7652758

Answer (score 0):

Next solution gives me needed behaviour

```
   onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
        if (didPop) return;
        final result = await showConfirmExitDialog(context);
        if (!context.mounted) return;
        if (result) Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
```