# change willpopscope to popscope in flutter

Tags: flutter

when I upgrade flutter
its show that willPobScope is deprecated and should change with popScope

any help with my code for back button notification

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final diffrence = DateTime.now().difference(timeBackPressed);
        final isExitWarning = diffrence >= const Duration(seconds: 2);
        timeBackPressed = DateTime.now();

        if (isExitWarning) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Press agin for exit", fontSize: 15);
          return false;
        } else {
          Fluttertoast.cancel();
          return true;
        }
      },)
```

Comment: its a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77529904/willpopscope-is-deprecated-in-flutter, read the answers deeply, there is documentation reference on the comments also

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
PopScope(
  canPop: false,
  onPopInvoked: (didPop) => handlePop(context),
  ...
)

Future<bool> handlePop(BuildContext context) async {
  final difference = DateTime.now().difference(timeBackPressed);
  final notPressed = timeBackPressed == null ||
          difference > toastDuration;

  if (notPressed) {
    timeBackPressed = now;
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Press agin for exit", fontSize: 15);
    return false;
  } else {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      SystemNavigator.pop();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      exit(0);
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```