# Flutter overide method back()

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I make the back button work in android the same way as home. If I click on back, the application is killed, but I need the back button to work the same way as home, that is, just hide the application with the state saved. I know that it is possible to track the pressing of the back button using the WillPopScope widget in the onWillPop method, but how can I make the application collapse?

I found the system_shortcuts package, but it is already outdated and does not support null safety for my project.

Problem with system_shortcuts:
i just add in pubspec system_shortcuts: ^1.0.0 and in my dart file import 'package:system_shortcuts/system_shortcuts.dart';

console:
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:system_shortcuts

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deactivate or override the Android "BACK" button, in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter)

Comment: no it just disables the back button

Comment: Can you provide sample code that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // todo
        return false;
      },
      child: ...);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my purpose I found package [move_to_background](https://pub.dev/packages/move_to_background), and use MoveToBackground.moveTaskToBack();

Answer (score 0):

You can run the app with system_shortcuts package by the below command

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

**OR**
if you want to keep your app on null safety then you can use [intent package](https://pub.dev/packages/intent) for navigating to home like android home button.

system_shortcuts package's home navigation code is

```
private void home() {
    this.activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));
}
```

You can call this java code by intent package like below.

```
Intent()
    ..setAction(Action.ACTION_MAIN)
    ..addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME")
    ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print(e));
```

**OR**
You can do it by flutter [methodChannel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)