# how to detect if the button back of the phone is pressed?

Tags: flutter

is it possible to detect that user clicked on the button back of the phone as this image  and change it functionality  for example if the user clicked on that button i want to take him to the page Data() not to the previous page .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD207.png)

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918186/11445944

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deactivate or override the Android "BACK" button, in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WillPopScope widget can detect your backpress

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      ///your code here...
      return false;
    },
    child:Scaffold(), 
  );
}
```

Comment: yes ! exactly chat i need thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate it to your desired page after acquired the BACK event.

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Data()),
```

Comment: and how can i detect that the user pressed the button back of the phone ?

Comment: Use WillPopScope method and return false. This method will detect BACK press.