# flutter back button home button recent buttton disable

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, disabled-control

i am created a launcher using flutter and dart for particular need.my launcher is only going to use by two companies.they only need the launcher first interface .so they are willling to disable the phone back button ,recent button,and home button .is it posssible to diable the use of these phone button using flutter or is it possible to disable through phone .bz when ever the launcher is activated only one interface .so no the company dont need go to back button home buton and recent button of the phone

my home button is not working now i did some permsions in android manifest ,but tried some ways to disable back button and recent buton not working.if anyone have any idea pls help

Comment: Using `WillPopScope` you can [disable the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter).

Comment: i done that .i want to disable control recent items button.how to fo that

Comment: pls some one help...i want to disable the recent button or i want to remove the funconality of recent button in my flutter launcher