# bug in Navigate from bottomNavigator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three screen. two of them are in my bottom navigator and the third one is that i will navigate to.
The problem is that when i want to come back from third screen using back button, it closes the app.

heres main.dart :

```
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: CustomBottomNav(),
      )
```

and bottomNav :

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            items:<BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                              BottomNavigationBarItem:(//bla bla),
                              BottomNavigationBarItem(//bla bla) ],
            tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Screen[index];
              },
            );
          },
        )
```

i navigate like this :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ThirdScreen()));
```

Comment: You might need to override the onBack logic to handle this case.

Comment: @tomerpacific can you provide an example? or more express please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deactivate or override the Android "BACK" button, in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916658/how-to-deactivate-or-override-the-android-back-button-in-flutter)